# What websites do you visit for up to date Malware info?

Tags: malware

I'm expanding my understanding of Malware a lot more, as it's currently 0! I know how it behaves and propagates most times, but I don't have a clue about the latest threats out there, what it exploits, what ports it uses, etc.

I did a quick Google and have come across the following sites:

http://www.securelist.com/
http://www.mcafee.com/us/mcafee-labs/threat-intelligence.aspx

But there a lot more - I just don't know which ones are the best out there.

Cam anyone help? Cheers.

ps* I am aware there is another thread like this, but it was created 2 years ago :)

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge a very good resource for learning malware analysis is [Offensive Computing](http://www.offensivecomputing.net)
They have a big (open to all) collection of malware to analyze and learn. you can also submit samples of malware.

From the website

> There is a noticeable lack of public sources of malware and malware analysis available. Those that were available were either for sale or limited to a small number of users. We provide resources such as live copies of malicious software, md5sums to search on and analysis of the malware to the general public. Offensive Computing currently has the largest publicly available malware collection on the Internet.

p.s. for some unknown reason the website is down at the time of writing this answer

Comment: Thanks! It's currently up, so I will have a thorough search of it today